# Servername Secure Connection - Loose Match

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, https, httpd.conf, hostname

We've updated our Apache deployment configuration to allow for non-www requests to our server (`https://example.com`). For https connections we needed this because the name didn't match the cert. This was good, recently though we noticed our local deployments secure environments (`https://chris.example.com`) are also pointing to this new deployment. We commented out the new deployment to confirm this was the change the caused it and it was. We presumed this was from the `servername` setting we had set. Here's our initial settings:

```
NameVirtualHost example.com:443
<VirtualHost example.com:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.example.com
    ServerName example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/example2017.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/ssl2017.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/example2017intermediate.pem
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    LogLevel notice
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/www.example.com/error.log
    LogFormat "%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}t %a %u %A %p %m %U %q %>s \"%{User-agent}i\"" w3c_extended
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/www.example.com/access.log w3c_extended
</VirtualHost>
```

After the commenting out worked we assumed it was the `ServerName` being a loose match and we read the following on the Apache site:

> Sometimes, the server runs behind a device that processes SSL, such as a reverse proxy, load balancer or SSL offload appliance. When this is the case, specify the https:// scheme and the port number to which the clients connect in the ServerName directive to make sure that the server generates the correct self-referential URLs.

-http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername

So we updated the `servername` the entry to:

```
ServerName https://example.com:443
```

this allowed the main page (`https://example.com`) to still load and redirect but the development environments (`https://chris.example.com`) were again being loaded from it. I was originally considering trying an explicit starting rule:

```
ServerName ^example.com
```

but I can't find anywhere saying the `servername` accepts regex. Is there a way to do this, or am I own the wrong path and the issue is elsewhere?

Here's the `httpd -S` output:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.0.0:443     is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1065)
         port 443 namevhost example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1065)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server *.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
         port 443 namevhost *.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
         port 443 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1046)
         port 443 namevhost chris.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1096)
         port 443 namevhost dan.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1129)
         port 443 namevhost rich.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1159)
         port 443 namevhost rich2.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1189)
         port 443 namevhost danny12.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1219)
         port 443 namevhost nick.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1249)
         port 443 namevhost cdn.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1300)
         port 443 namevhost origin_server.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1316)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1034)
         port 80 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1034)
         port 80 namevhost dfw.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1084)
         port 80 namevhost chris.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1114)
         port 80 namevhost dan.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1147)
         port 80 namevhost rich.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1177)
         port 80 namevhost rich2.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1207)
         port 80 namevhost danny12.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1237)
         port 80 namevhost nick.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1267)
         port 80 namevhost origin_server.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1279)
         port 80 namevhost cdn.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1290)
Syntax OK
```

The new deployment started at line 1064 and ended at 1081.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more thorough investigation in chat it appears that there were **two** `NameBasedVirtualHost` statements, one for `*:443` and another one for `example.com:443` with the former having all subdomains `VirtualHost` declarations and the latter having only one for `example.com` itself.

Making it uniform with one `NameBasedVirtualHost *:443` declaration and all subdomains and main domain referring to it fixed the problem.

Comment: Our `httpd.conf` has `ServerName *.example.com` only under `Section 2: 'Main' server configuration`. The `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` doesn't have that at line 74. Line 74 is `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`, there is no code base set there. I've moved the loose matching configuration in the `httpd.conf` to be the last record but that had the same result.

Comment: Could you please post output of `httpd -S` after these changes?

Comment: Your configuration dump still suggests you have a wildcard set as ServerName under your first :443 virtualhost entry in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf line 74, even if it is not used for any actual site. Please check all of your VirtualHost *:443 entries for wildcard ServerName, it is there a 100%.

Comment: Line 74 is still the same in the ssl.conf. I didn't edit anything in there. I moved the newer looser rule to the end, was that not what I was suppose to be doing? The `ssl.conf` has no code deployments listed in it so I don't see how it could be set to point to the correct/incorrect one.

Comment: Could you please post a contents of `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` from ssl.conf?

Comment: I've posted 74 and onward, is that enough or do you need all lines? Should I just delete the commented lines to remove clutter?

Comment: I think you have to set *some* ServerName there in the `_default_` as I think it is interfering with the rest of your configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55295/discussion-between-chris85-and-peter-zhabin).